# I'm confused about exactly how a subgroup of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ can be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I have read that there exists a subgroup $H$ of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ such that $H \cong \Bbb Z$.

If $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z:=\{(a,b)|a,b \in \Bbb Z\}$

With the group operation $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c, b+d)$.

Then by defining a map

$\phi:\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z$

$\phi:(a,b) \rightarrow c $

Then I would assume that the only isomorphic subgroup would be $H:=\{(0,d)|d \in \Bbb Z \}$. Is that correct?

Comment: It’s analogous to thinking about linear subspaces of $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$. Any line through the origin is a subspace, not just the two axes. They can “straddle” more than one coordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the "lines" of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, i.e

$$\{(an, bn) \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

with $a, b \in \mathbb{N}_0$ fixed.

Comment: Ah I think I see now. So say we chose $H={(n,2n)| n \in \Bbb Z}$, if we then quotiented out H from $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ would this quotient be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z_2 $ ? Or am I still thinking of the isomorphisms incorrectly ? (its the fact that its a direct product that throws me a bit )

Comment: I think that the quotient would be just $\Bbb{Z}$. Where are you getting the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ from? It would be if $H={\{(2n,2n)| n \in \Bbb Z}\} $instead.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I incorrectly visualized the set as having "gaps" as $(2n, 2n)$ does.

Answer (score 2):

What about the diagonal subgroup?

$$H=\{(d,d):d \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$